# "display: none" is getting added to google places autocomplete input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api

I have an angularjs application, and I am using [this directive](https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete) to get the google-maps-api places autocomplete in the following input field .

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" g-places-autocomplete class="" options="autocompleteOptions" ng-model="location">
</div>
```

The issue is that the input field's style is getting set as `display: none;`, and the autocomplete is not working.

When I manually set the property to `display: block;`, everything is working fine. Am I missing something in using the `g-places-autocomplete` directive?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing all right. The Directive has issue. As temporaly solution
set "display" in style.

Eg

> <input type="text" autocomplete="off" g-places-autocomplete class="" options="autocompleteOptions" ng-model="location" style="display:initial !important;">

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by an update to Google's experimental version of the Places Service. Turns out that by default if you do not specify an API version you get the non-stable/non-release version (???) of the API. Specifying v3 when loading the API guarantees the latest stable version, while specifying v3.xx gets whatever sub-version you want. In this case 3.31 is the current release build and did not have this issue, but anyone who did not specify a version received 3.32 which is currently under development.

Comment: format for specifying version is as follows: (v=3.26) `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&key=YOUR API KEY"></script>`